# Gather nodetool status output via JMX Mbeans

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nodetool

Is there a way to get the information provided by nodetool status using  JMX Mbean? I would like query the information using the JMX

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageService` is the JMX which gives the details.